# A question on the convergence of integrals after a u-sub?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Why exactly do some integrals which are simplified using a u -sub, converge as we tend to infinity whereas others do not?
for instance, consider
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\ln(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$$
on integrating by parts, this doesn't converge. But
using the method mentioned here [on integrating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\ln(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$,  ][1]

[1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1239250/879009, it does. Why is this?

I have started this bounty to award the existing answer, new answers will not be eligible for the bounty

Comment: That integral converges

Comment: yes, but the first doesn't on using parts

Comment: I like your "U-sub", that I had never seen before ; any connection with "U-boats"...

Comment: what do you mean?,@JeanMarie

Comment: I was joking. But you must realize that "U-sub" is a jargon word maybe used by your instructor but not known in the rest of the world. Why don't you say "a change of variable" ?

Comment: oh, they are similar anyway. Both are sneaky, unexpected and very, very effective!

Comment: *"u-sub"* is known well enough in enough of the world that the Wikipedia article puts that phrase before *"change of variable"* in its list of alternatives. Hardly something worth commenting on, and very certainly not an idiosyncrasy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$That integral converges. Since $x\mapsto x\cdot\ln x$ can be continuously extended to a function on $[0,\infty)$, as is the denominator, we don't need to worry about convergence on the lower end as $x\to0$. For the upper tail as $x\to\infty$, note that $|\ln x|=\ln x<x$ so the integrand is dominated by: $$\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$$And the integral of each term here clearly converges.

$$I:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}\d x$$Definitely exists as a finite real number, then. When integrating by parts, you should instead perform IBP on: $$\int_\varepsilon^R\frac{x\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}\d x$$For large $R$, small $\varepsilon$, obtain an expression, and *then* take $R\to\infty,\varepsilon\to0^+$. I suspect you antidifferentiated $\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ and differentiated $\ln x$. Let's fix $R,\varepsilon$ large and small, and see what happens: $$\begin{align}-\frac{1}{2(1+x^2)}\cdot\ln x\Big|_\varepsilon^R+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\varepsilon}^R\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\d x&=-\frac{\ln R}{2(1+R^2)}+\frac{\ln\varepsilon}{2(1+\varepsilon^2)}\\&+\frac{1}{2}\int_\varepsilon^R\left[\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right]\d x\\&=-\frac{\ln R}{2(1+R^2)}+\frac{\ln\varepsilon}{2(1+\varepsilon^2)}\\&+\frac{\ln R-\ln\varepsilon}{2}+\left[-\frac{1}{4}\ln(1+x^2)\right]_\varepsilon^R\\&=\frac{2R^2\cdot\ln R-(1+R^2)\ln(1+R^2)}{4(1+R^2)}\\&+\frac{(1+\varepsilon^2)\ln(1+\varepsilon^2)-2\varepsilon^2\cdot\ln\varepsilon}{4(1+\varepsilon^2)}\end{align}$$*No issues whatsoever*. This is why it is sometimes important to appeal to the limit definition of improper integrals. Now, if you take $R\to\infty$ and $\varepsilon\to0^+$ (in either order, it clearly doesn't matter) we deal with the terms in $R$ by dividing through $R^2$: $$\frac{2\cdot\ln R-(1+R^{-2})\ln(1+R^2)}{4(1+R^{-2})}\sim\frac{2\ln R-\ln(1+R^2)}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\ln\frac{R^2}{1+R^2}\overset{R\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{4}\ln(1)=0$$Let's look at the terms in $\varepsilon$: $\ln(1+\varepsilon^2)\to\ln(1)=0$, and that $\varepsilon^2\cdot\ln\varepsilon\to0$ is well known. Therefore the expression in $\varepsilon$ vanishes.

Therefore $I=0+0=0$, after taking $R\to\infty,\varepsilon\to0^+$, exactly as expected! Integration by parts *does* work, if done carefully.

This method also shows - if you take $\varepsilon\to0^+$ but $R\to1$ - that: $$\int_0^1\frac{x\cdot\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}\d x=-\frac{1}{4}\ln2$$Using a much more elementary method than in the linked post. Just ignore the $\varepsilon$ terms as zero - as shown - and evaluate the expression in $R$ at $R=1$.

Comment: i see, thanks!!

Comment: @fhhh See my update. I have directly addressed your integration by parts concerns

Comment: Thanks a lot for the though explanation! Is there any way I can award a bounty without waiting for two days for this answer?

Comment: @fhhh That is very kind. But no, you can't.

Comment: oh, that's a pity, I'll award it in two days then.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Fshrike

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever You’re very welcome!